ObservableValidator Int Validation not working
Im using ObservableValidator  for validating an int value,
I have implemented ObservableValidator in my viewmodel,
 [ObservableProperty]
 [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of Pins must be greater than 0")]
 [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Number of Pins must be greater than 0")]
 private int createPartLibraryNumberOfPins;

It works for most cases, But when the value is empty, in the GUI I can see the error, but in ViewModel
HasErrors property is not updated.
Can you please suggest a way to update HasErros in ViewModel.

Regards
Jestin CI

You should try using a Value Converter:
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is int intValue
            ? intValue.ToString()
            : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is string stringValue
            ? int.Parse(stringValue)
            : 0;
    }
}

